# Angular Redux retrieve data to state using entities

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I have reducer like this:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<PackageScenario> {
  loading: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<PackageScenario> = createEntityAdapter<PackageScenario>({
  selectId: packageScenario => packageScenario.id
});

export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
  loading: false
});

const _psReducer = createReducer<State>(
  initialState,
  on(getPackageScenariosActionInit, state => ({...state, loading: true})),
  on(getPackageScenariosActionSuccess, (state, {packageScenarios}) => 
    adapter.upsertMany(packageScenarios, {...state, loading: false})
  )
);

export function psReducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return _psReducer(state, action);
}
```

I have problem with this line: `on(getPackageScenariosActionSuccess, (state, {packageScenarios}) => adapter.upsertMany(packageScenarios, {...state, loading: false})`

On console I got error

> ERROR TypeError: entities is not iterable

Any idea, why this not working?

--UPDATE

Action:

```
export const getPackageScenariosActionSuccess = createAction(
  '[Package Scenario] Success get package scenarios',
  props<{ packageScenarios: PackageScenario[];} >()
);
```

-- UPDATE

Full stack trace

> ERROR TypeError: entities is not iterable
>       at upsertManyMutably (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:170842:30)
>       at Object.operation [as upsertMany] (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:170597:27)
>       at https://localhost:4200/main.js:2656:505
>       at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:174937:26
>       at psReducer (https://localhost:4200/main.js:2661:12)
>       at combination (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:173590:37)
>       at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:174394:27
>       at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:173670:20
>       at computeNextEntry (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:172508:21)
>       at recomputeStates (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:172561:15)

Comment: Are you sure that `packageScenarios` is a list ? can you provide  the action `getPackageScenariosActionSuccess` as well

Comment: Sure, look in edited post

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code. Do you have a longer stack trace ?

Comment: What do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: The full error message.

Comment: Sure, updated in post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201857/discussion-between-wandrille-and-gadziu).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In action, I pass the object `{ PackageScenario[] }`, but in service where I have action dispatched, I pass only array.

In service it was:

```
this.hubConnection.on('GetPackageScenariosList', (packageScenarios: PackageScenario[]) => {
          this.store$.dispatch(PSActions.getPackageScenariosActionSuccess(packageScenarios));
        });
```

It should be:

```
this.hubConnection.on('GetPackageScenariosList', (packageScenarios: PackageScenario[]) => {
          this.store$.dispatch(PSActions.getPackageScenariosActionSuccess({packageScenarios}));
        });
```